# Combine code xaml.cs with other class .cs

Tags: c#, xaml

i have a problem. In WPF I have a listview and there are options to choose (radiobutton). The list of options is taken from the function of other class and it works (in XAML.cs). If i choose option from listview i would like to send index of choosen option to function of other class (in .cs). I looked for answer on my question, but nothing. Please for help. Thank you. 
Sorry for my language, but i'm not native speaker.
A piece of code XAML.cs . I would like to send variable table

```
    void selitemtables(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        TranslateTable t = (TranslateTable)Listview_table.SelectedItem;
        int table = (int)Listview_table.SelectedIndex;

        MessageBox.Show(table.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show("Selected: "+t);          
    }
```

I would like to send variable table to this function in .cs

```
        public int chooseTable(int index)
    {

        return index;
    }
```

I would like to send table as parameter to chooseTable(int index)

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add some code. How do you get a list of options from other class? How do you want to send chosen index to other class?

Comment: Why do you try to find index if you already have selected item from table? Actually you could directly bind  your listView  and selected item to model property without selitemtables method.